# Calling Methods in Java Constructor For Boolean Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm currently doing dev on an inherited Spring boot app, part of it is sending an API POST request with the boolean of whether a soccer match is finished or not (`resulted`). I noticed that the design of the class was such:

```
//parent class
public class Fixture {

    private final FixtureType type;
    private final Team homeTeam;
    private final Team awayTeam;

    public Fixture(@JsonProperty("type") final FixtureType type,
                   @JsonProperty("homeTeam") final Team homeTeam,
                   @JsonProperty("awayTeam") final Team awayTeam

    ) {
        this.type = type;
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
    }

    public boolean isResulted() {
        return false;
    } 
    /* 
     other methods
    */
}
```

```
//child class
public class Result extends Fixture {

    private final Outcome outcome;

    public Result(@JsonProperty("type") final FixtureType type,
                  @JsonProperty("homeTeam") final Team homeTeam,
                  @JsonProperty("awayTeam") final Team awayTeam,
                  @JsonProperty("outcome") final Outcome outcome) {

        super(type, homeTeam, awayTeam);
        this.outcome = outcome;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isResulted() {
        return true;
    }
    /* 
     other methods
    */
}
```

In the Swagger documentation, the request specifies that `"resulted": true` needs to be a field in the JSON POST request. Now I can add that field into the constructor, but that would mean changing a load of tests and code that calls this constructor. My solution was to call the `isResulted()` method in the constructor itself. I've never done this before, but this works. Is there any reason that this design below would create issues in the long run?

```
public class Result extends Fixture {

     private final boolean resulted;

     public Result (){
      super();
      resulted = isResulted();
     }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("resulted")
    public boolean isResulted() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what's the purpose of having a private field that is not used anywhere. I'm also not sure I understand the problem you'd like to have solved.

There's a possible approach that is both more flexible and compatible with your previous code:

```
public class Result extends Fixture {

     private final boolean resulted;

     public Result (boolean resulted){
      super();
      this.resulted = resulted;
     }

     public Result (){
        this(true); // sets the default value
     }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("resulted")
    public boolean isResulted() {
        return resulted;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Fabio, thanks for the response. I've added the actual constructor code for better context. Basically the `isResulted()` method gets called elsewhere in the application which is why I'm loathe to change the design.

Comment: Now it makes sense.